# How to unit test a chained method using Jasmine

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine

I'm having a problem unit testing the following method:

```
 $scope.changeLocation = function (url) {
        $location.path(url).search({ ref: "outline" });
    };
```

I've written the following unit test that currently fails with this error (TypeError: Cannot read property 'search' of undefined):

```
var $locationMock = { path: function () { }, search: function () { } };

it('changeLocation should update location correctly', function () {
        $controllerConstructor('CourseOutlineCtrl', { $scope: $scope, $location: $locationMock });

        var url = "/url/";
        spyOn($locationMock, "path");
        spyOn($locationMock, "search");

        $scope.changeLocation(url);

        expect($locationMock.search).toHaveBeenCalledWith({ ref: "outline" });
        expect($locationMock.path).toHaveBeenCalledWith(url);
    });
```

If I change my function to the following, the test passes:

```
$scope.changeLocation = function (url) {
        $location.path(url);
        $location.search({ ref: "outline" });
    };
```

How do I unit test this method when I'm using method chaining? Do I need to setup my $locationMock differently?  For the life of me I cannot figure this out.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

That is because your mock does not return location object to be able to chain through. Using Jasmine 2.0 you can change your mock to:

```
var $locationMock = { path: function () { return $locationMock; }, 
                      search: function () { return $locationMock; } };
```

and

```
spyOn($locationMock, "path").and.callThrough();
spyOn($locationMock, "search").and.callThrough(); //if you are chaining from search
```

or add:

```
spyOn($locationMock, "path").and.returnValue($locationMock);
spyOn($locationMock, "search").and.returnValue($locationMock); //if you are chaining from search
```

Or just create a spy object (less code):

```
var $locationMock = jasmine.createSpyObj('locationMock', ['path', 'search']);
```

and

```
$locationMock.path.and.returnValue($locationMock);
$locationMock.search.and.returnValue($locationMock); //if you are chaining from search
```

Comment: I was using Jasmine 1.x so the .and.returnValue() was failing.  This works great for Jasmine 2.0 though.  I changed the .and.returnValue() to .andReturns() to get it working with 1.x.  I'll upgrade Jasmine soon.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: Thanks @PSL for the pointer. Returning the same object in the methods to be chained (builder pattern) is the key here. Neatly illustrated.

Answer (score 0):

try :

```
spyOn($locationMock, "path").and.callThrough();
```

Else you'r calling search on a mock not $location