# AngularJS karma testing with chained promises

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine, karma-runner

Here is the function in the Controller:

```
angular.module("MyMod")
.controller("MyController", function(UserData, mtcLogService, $state,
    BroadcastService, $scope, $rootScope, ChartsService, PaxCountSummaryService) {

    self.waveCountSummary = function() {
        if (self.program.programID !== undefined) {
            PaxCountSummaryService.getWaveCountChartSummary(self.program.programID)
                .then(function(data) {
                    self.totalWaveCount = data[data.length - 1].count;
                    data.pop();
                    return (data || []).map(_.bind(ChartsService.tasksCountToChartData, this, _, "unknown"));
                })
                .then(function(chart) {
                    return self.replaceContentsOf(self.waveCountChartData, chart);
                });
        }
    };
});
```

Here is my working test:

```
fit("My test", inject(function ($rootScope, $controller, $q) {

    var results = [{
        pop: sinon.spy(),
        count: 1
    }];

    mockPaxCountSummaryService.getWaveCountChartSummary
        .returns($q.resolve(results));

    testController = $controller("PaxCountSummaryController", {
        $state: state,
        $scope: scope,
        $rootScope: $rootScope,
        PaxCountSummaryService: mockPaxCountSummaryService
    });

    testController.program = testProgram;
    testController.totalWaveCount = null;

    expect(testController.totalWaveCount).toBe(null);

    testController.waveCountSummary();
    scope.$apply();

    expect(testController.totalWaveCount).toBe(1);
}));
```

Ok, this test works. But how would I get to the second THEN in the promise chain so I can test if REPLACECONTENTSOF is called?

Any help on this?

Comment: Try changing `$q.resolve(results)` to `$q.when(results)`. I'm not sure resolve will return the promise that you need to return.

Comment: You probably want to use mocks.  See this question for guidance http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27971729/how-to-unit-test-a-chained-method-using-jasmine

Answer (score 1):

Well, this is one of those times where I got turned around with multiple issues but it does work as expected. I just needed to create a spy for REPLACECONTENTSOF.

Here is working final test:

```
fit("MyTest.", inject(function($controller, $q) {

    var results = [{
        pop: sinon.spy(),
        count: 1
    }];

    mockPaxCountSummaryService.getWaveCountChartSummary
        .returns($q.resolve(results));

    testController = $controller("PaxCountSummaryController", {
        $state: state,
        $scope: scope,
        PaxCountSummaryService: mockPaxCountSummaryService
    });

    testController.program = testProgram;
    testController.replaceContentsOf = sinon.spy();
    testController.totalWaveCount = null;

    expect(testController.replaceContentsOf.callCount).toBe(0);

    testController.waveCountSummary();
    scope.$apply();

    expect(testController.totalWaveCount).toBe(1);
    expect(testController.replaceContentsOf.callCount).toBe(1);
}));
```