# How to test chained method in Jasmine Karma

Tags: javascript, jasmine, angular-material, karma-jasmine, mddialog

I am trying to test the below piece of code with Jasmine Karma.
But how to mock chained method inside `$mdDialog.show()`?

```
// Actual code that need to be test.

this.showAlert = function ( error ) {
    console.log("dfsfs");
    $mdDialog.show(
        $mdDialog.alert()
            .clickOutsideToClose( true )
            .title( 'Error' )
            .textContent( error )
            .ok( 'OK' )
    );
}
```

The test code I'm trying is:

```
describe('Testing showAlert()', function(){ 

it('should exist',function(){ 
    expect(ErrorHandler.showAlert).toBeDefined(); 
}); 

it('should open the alert dialog',function(){ 
    var message="Some message"; 
    ErrorHandler.showAlert(message); 
    expect(ErrorHandler.showAlert).toHaveBeenCalledWith(messa‌​ge); 
});
```

});

Comment: What do you want to test? Do you want to assert  .tittle() or .ok() methods being called, for example? Or what?

Comment: @Sergeon I want to test the full .show method. I tried to spy the alert but it  is showing as undefined and so in the chained methods are not working.

This is the code that I wrote..

describe('Testing showAlert()',function(){
  it('should exist',function(){
   expect(ErrorHandler.showAlert).toBeDefined();
  });
  
  it('should open the alert dialog',function(){
   var message="Some message";
   ErrorHandler.showAlert(message);
   expect(ErrorHandler.showAlert).toHaveBeenCalledWith(message);
  });
  });

Comment: Have you tried [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27971729/how-to-unit-test-a-chained-method-using-jasmine)?

Comment: @WinterSoldier yes I tried that also but no luck.